# Data migration from mysql to parse: how to insert same hashed password from mysql to parse?

Tags: database, hash, parse-platform, passwords, password-encryption

I am migrating from `mysql` to [`parse`](https://parseplatform.org/). How can I handle the migration of hashed passwords?

Comment: Are you able to share your current hashing mechanism? Parse uses bcrypt so you could be fortunate if you already use bcrypt?

Comment: You would lose your session though, so your users would need to log back in. Parse does supports authenticating against an external service, if your current app supports oAuth: https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#custom-authentication